# Matlab 'trimf' function commands

Tags: matlab

```
 y = trimf(x,[a b c]);
```

How to find corresponding membership value at any point between `a` and `c`.

Say,

```
x = (0:2.5:10)';

y = trimf(x,[-2.5 0 2.5])
```

Now say I want to find corresponding membership value at point `1.2` 
(which is between `-0.25` and `+0.25`)

Comment: It's quite easy using simple arithmetic using the equations for a triangular shape membership function, but I guess you want to use the fuzzy logic toolbox? Also, are you sure the values for `[a b c]` are like you want them? You say in the bottom line "which is between -0.25 and 0.25..."? What do you mean? I can't see how that statement is correct.

Comment: @StewieGriffin

(http://in.mathworks.com/help/fuzzy/trimf.html ) ... Please have a look at this.
I'm stuck at.... how to calculate the corresponding membership value at any point between 'a' and 'c' . where a & c are the base points(suppose along x-axis) of the triangle (mem. func.) and b is the height(suppose along Y-axis). 
So at any point between 'a' & 'c' if I draw a straight line vertically.It will intersect the arm 'ab' . Now I need the corresponding value along Y-axis.

How to do that?

Hope this time it Clarifies my problem!
Thanks!

Comment: This is a simple algebraic expression. Split the line into two sections. one going from `a` to `b`, and one going from `b` to `c`. Now, set up the equation for each of those sections (`y = k*x + h`). Find `h` and `k` for each section. Now you can just insert any `x` to find the `y`-value. This is elementary junior high school math, not really a programming question.

Comment: Again .. cmmon dude... every body knows this one...may be there is a communication gap...any way.. 
I want to use trimf function and want to get the values! is it possible ?

Comment: Is this correct: _"... but I guess you want to use the fuzzy logic toolbox?"_ I.e. even though you have `a,b,c` you still want to use `trimf` and not simple algebra? If so: I don't have the fuzzy logic toolbox so I can't help, sorry.